# Optimistic Lock in UPDATE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking, common-table-expression

I want to execute a single update query and have the result indicate to me in some way between three possible outcomes; successful, version conflict or entity not found

Example UPDATE query:

```
update vessel_clearance vc
    set status = "blah",
        last_updated_at = {new_ts},
        expiry = {some_time}
    where vc.id = {vesselclearanceid}
        and vc.last_updated_at = {current_version_ts}
```

Is this possible? I have experimented with the `WITH` clause but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Wrap it in a CTE with `returning id` at the bottom, and then make the main query `select count(*) from <CTE name>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `vessel_clearance.id` is the PK, so below `UPDATE` and `SELECT` can only ever find a single row.

Here is a **single statement** to achieve your objective:

```sql
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE vessel_clearance vc
   SET    status = "blah"
        , last_updated_at = {new_ts}
        , expiry = {some_time}
   WHERE  vc.id = {vesselclearanceid}
   AND    vc.last_updated_at = {current_version_ts}
   RETURNING 1  -- see below
   )
SELECT COALESCE(
     (SELECT 'UPDATE_APPLIED'   FROM upd)
   , (SELECT 'VERSION_CONFLICT' FROM vessel_clearance WHERE id = {vesselclearanceid})
           , 'ENTITY_NOT_FOUND'
   ) AS result;
```

`RETURNING 1` because it only matters that a row is returned. My query does not care about returned values.

The row is only locked if the `UPDATE` actually happens. `SELECT` does not lock the row in Postgres. So much for "Optimistic Locking".
The outer `SELECT` returns 'UPDATE_APPLIED' in this case.

If, and only if, it doesn't happen, another `SELECT` checks for the existence of the given ID. If found, the only remaining answer 'VERSION_CONFLICT' is returned.

Else we get 'ENTITY_NOT_FOUND'.

Notably, this is a single statement. CTEs and the outer `SELECT`, all see the **same snapshot** of the table. So there is no race condition.

Comment: I removed sqlc.arg(..) call from the original question.  sqlc is a tool that compiles sql into Go code...my bad for the misleading info.

Comment: I removed that bit accordingly.

Comment: This is actually two queries in one, but it's still a single call. Both queries see the same snapshot and should be optimal if indexes are set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below. It will return the number of rows.

That said, if you are using a library from another language, update/delete/insert methods often will return the number of rows affected.

```
with update_query as (
  update vessel_clearance vc
     set status = "blah",
         last_updated_at = {new_ts},
         expiry = {some_time}
   where vc.id = sqlc.arg(vesselclearanceid)
     and vc.last_updated_at = {current_version_ts}
   returning id
)
select count(*) from update_query;
```

Comment: sure, but I need to know if there was no update because there is no entity with the supplied id OR if there is an entity but the version didn't match...this way I can differentiate between NO_ENTITY and VERSION_CONFLICT

Comment: However, this is nearly it...just need to add a subquery to the select to count the rows matching the id

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I don't think you can do this in a single query.

The UPDATE statement will return the number of affected rows, and that corresponds directly to the rows matching a search predicate value of true (not unknown, not false). If the search predicate includes the version verification then it won't match a different version value and will return zero, even if there are rows for a partial match of the predicate ( only for `id` in this case).

Having said that, you can do this using Pessimitic Locking. Running one query to check for predicate #1 (without the version verification) and then a second one with full predicate (with version verification). This, of course, defeats the goal of using Optimistic Locking.

Comment: it can be done, see answer marked as correct.

Comment: PostgreSQL amazed me sometimes.